# impossible to install angular / command ng not found

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I'm working on an Angular project and until yesterday it was working perfectly. Yesterday after I launched my project and I got this error message:

> ng command not found.

I tried everything to solve it, I uninstall Angular and reinstall it with
`npm install -g @angular/cli`, but I got this message:

```
   npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated
   see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 
   npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
```

I read many forums and tried implementing few things but it just doesn't work.
Can you help me, please?
(Sorry for my English, I'm French; I'm a beginner with Angular so I'm not aware of all the technical details)

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Did you run `ng --version` to check whether the install was successful or not?

Comment: maybe you're calling ng command in a wrong directory. call ng command  where package.json is

Comment: If I tip in "ng --version"" I got the message "ng is not recognised has a command or a programm". And I call ng in the folder of my angular project. The thing I don't understand is that it was working just fine for 2 mounths. And now it doesn't.